Installing AWS CLI v1 on Ubuntu 24 does not work (but works fine on Ubuntu 22)
I have the following dockerfile, which installs AWS CLI according to Amazon's instructions
On Ubuntu Jammy, this works fine. The image builds and aws command works as expected.
FROM ubuntu:jammy

RUN apt update && apt install -y curl python3 python3-venv unzip
RUN curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip" && \
    unzip awscli-bundle.zip && \
    python3 ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws

RUN aws --version

However, if I change FROM ubuntu:jammy to FROM ubuntu:noble the installation fails with an error:
#0 10.49 Running cmd: /usr/bin/python3 -m venv /usr/local/aws
#0 10.49 Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/python -m pip install --no-binary :all: --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file://. setuptools_scm-3.3.3.tar.gz
#0 10.49 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 10.49   File "//./awscli-bundle/install", line 258, in <module>
#0 10.49     main()
#0 10.49   File "//./awscli-bundle/install", line 238, in main
#0 10.49     pip_install_packages(opts.install_dir)
#0 10.49   File "//./awscli-bundle/install", line 148, in pip_install_packages
#0 10.49     _install_setup_deps(python, '.')
#0 10.49   File "//./awscli-bundle/install", line 167, in _install_setup_deps
#0 10.49     run(
#0 10.49   File "//./awscli-bundle/install", line 88, in run
#0 10.49     raise BadRCError("Bad rc (%s) for cmd '%s': %s" % (
#0 10.49 BadRCError: Bad rc (1) for cmd '/usr/local/aws/bin/python -m pip install --no-binary :all: --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file://. setuptools_scm-3.3.3.tar.gz': Looking in links: file://.
#0 10.49 Processing ./setuptools_scm-3.3.3.tar.gz
#0 10.49   Installing build dependencies: started
#0 10.49   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
#0 10.49   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 10.49
#0 10.49   × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#0 10.49   │ exit code: 2
#0 10.49   ╰─> [54 lines of output]
#0 10.49       Looking in links: file://.
#0 10.49       ERROR: Exception:
#0 10.49       Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
#0 10.49           status = run_func(*args)
#0 10.49                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
#0 10.49           return func(self, options, args)
#0 10.49                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
#0 10.49           requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
#0 10.49                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
#0 10.49           result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
#0 10.49                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
#0 10.49           state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
#0 10.49                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
#0 10.49           self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
#0 10.49           if not criterion.candidates:
#0 10.49                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
#0 10.49           return bool(self._sequence)
#0 10.49                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
#0 10.49           return any(self)
#0 10.49                  ^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
#0 10.49           return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
#0 10.49                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 44, in _iter_built
#0 10.49           for version, func in infos:
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 297, in iter_index_candidate_infos
#0 10.49           result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
#0 10.49                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 890, in find_best_candidate
#0 10.49           candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
#0 10.49                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 817, in find_all_candidates
#0 10.49           collected_sources = self._link_collector.collect_sources(
#0 10.49                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 480, in collect_sources
#0 10.49           find_links_sources = collections.OrderedDict(
#0 10.49                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 481, in <genexpr>
#0 10.49           build_source(
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/sources.py", line 242, in build_source
#0 10.49           path = url_to_path(location)
#0 10.49                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 10.49         File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/urls.py", line 43, in url_to_path
#0 10.49           raise ValueError(
#0 10.49       ValueError: non-local file URIs are not supported on this platform: 'file://.'

Why does happen and is there a way I can fix it? I have tried installing Python3.10 (via the Deadsnakes PPA) and using that instead, but it produces the same error.
FWIW, on Ubuntu 22 it's also possible to simply do apt install awscli however, this no longer seems to be available in Ubuntu 24.

You can check this link - How to Install AWS CLI on Ubuntu 24.04
sudo snap install aws-cli --classic 
aws --version

or other options available on the page.
